# Not able to select multiple sentences in the HTML Page in UIWebView

Tags: iphone, html, uiwebview, selection, sentence

I have the HTML Page below like this:

`<html>`

`<body>`

`<div id='0>`

`<span id='0'>Hi </span>`

`<span id='1'>How </span>`

`<span id='2'>Are </span>`

`<span id='3'>You</span>`

`</div>`

`<br><br>`

`<div id='1>`

`<span id='4'>welcome </span>`

`<span id='5'>to </span>`

`<span id='6'>our </span>`

`<span id='7'>place</span>`

`</div>`
`<br><br>`
`</body>`
`</html>`

I am trying to select multiple sentences in a iPhone webView loaded with a HTML like this.
But i am select instead it select the block of senetences.

What i have to change?

Answer (score 1):

To start, you shouldn't have HTML elements with the same IDs. Have you worked with HTML before? Check out http://w3schools.com/html/.

Also, what do you want to correct? Your question is vague of your intentions. If you want to select multiple sentences, put each sentence in a `<p>` element, you should be able to do so.